# Trouble finding the right selector clause when the variable I want to select by isn't contained in the parent of the element I want to style

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the css I need to change element, only when value[@as$="selector"] matches the correct value.

So for example if I wanted to change the text color of element to orange for examples sake.

I've tried a number of ways of selecting the correct element, but I don't think I am structuring my css selection tree correctly

```
<document>
  <tag>
    <another tag>
      <bnother tag>
        <value as="selector"/>
      </bnother tag>
    </another tag>
  </tag>
  <head>
    <irrelevant>
    </irrelevant>
  </head>
  <body>
   <element>
     <p>Words</p>
   </element>
  </body>
</document>
```

Expected is that Words becomes Orange, currently I can't get my css to select that element when the right conditions are met

Comment: It isn’t possible to select anything but the `value` element itself here based on its attribute, with that structure. CSS can only select downwards or to the right in the DOM tree, not upwards or to the left.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case, thanks for the answer though